# Adding a Swift system library to an xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have [a small Swift library](https://github.com/hampelm/swift-gdal) intended to import a c library for use in Swift.

I'd like to use that in a "hello world" Mac app I have built in Xcode. This seems like a very simple use-case, but I have not been able to figure out specific steps will let me include that swift library -- add to targets? import the library project into xcode? build as a framework and add? This feels very elementary, but I can't find an up-to-date how-to for Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2.

Comment: Sorry but what you seem to have built is a package, not a framework. If it's a package, it is directly sharable through github, as you have it. But a package cannot depend upon a framework or library (other than another package).

Comment: Thanks! In the repository, I link to two other packages that seem to use this strategy to make a c/c++ library available through Swift. If this isn't the correct approach, do you have a pointer to a working one?

Comment: I should also add, while I'm not new to programming, I clearly am very new to macos native work, so if I'm effectively asking "where do I put the wheels on this boat?", I appreciate any course correction and pointers.

Comment: Well I could just be wrong. There are WWDC 2019 talks on both packages and binary frameworks so it might be worth watching those. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2019/

Comment: On the other hand it's a little unclear to me what your goal is. If you simply want to share this code with _yourself_ you could just use a workspace.

Comment: I'll check those out, thanks! My primary goal is to be able use the C library in my swift project, and it would be nice if it was repeatable so others could take advantage of it. At this point I'm mostly curious because it seems like a straightforward use case, but the incantations have eluded me!